# use multiprocess.Pool.map in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, multiprocess

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Acc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def multiprocess(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        result = pool.map(self.run, [1]*30)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def run(self, i):
        self.count += i
        return self.count

a = Acc()
a.multiprocess()
print(a.count)
```

I suppose the output should be *30*, but it is *0*. I don't know how `multiprocess.Pool.map` works and how it cooperate with a class. Please tell me in detail.

By the way, if I print self.count inside like

```
    def run(self, i):
        print(self.count)
        self.count += i
        return self.count
```

It gives

```
0
1
0
1
00

1
10

1
00

11

0
1
00

1001



11

0
10

10

1
```

More confusing, why there have mixing 0 and 1.

Comment: [Thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) may give you help

Comment: Multiprocessing works by *copying* objects between processes. The ``self`` in the pool processes are not the same as the ``self`` in the main process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's have the printout be a bit more orderly by adding `flush=True` to the print statement so that each print output occupies its own line:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Acc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def multiprocess(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        result = pool.map(self.run, [1]*30)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def run(self, i):
        print('i =', self.count, flush=True)
        self.count += i
        return self.count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Acc()
    a.multiprocess()
    print('a.count =', a.count)
```

Prints:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 0
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 1
i = 0
i = 1
i = 1
a.count = 0
```

**Analysis**

Now let's analyze what is happening. The creation of `a = Acc()` is done by the main process. The multiprocessing pool processes are executing is a different address space so when they execute your worker function, `self.run`, object `a` must be serialized/de-serialized to the address space of the process that will be executing the worker function. In that new address space `self.count` comes across with the initial value of 0, which is printed, and then is incremented to 1 and returned. Meanwhile, in parallel, object `a` is being serialized/de-serialized 3 more times so 3 other processes can do the same processing and they, too, will also print 0 and return the value 1. But since all this incrementing is occurring to the copies of `a` that exist in address spaces other than the main process's address space, the original `a` in the main process remains unmodified. So as the `map` function continues to execute and `a` is further copied from the main process to the processing pool, it is always with `self.count = 0`.

Then the question becomes why is `i = 1` instead of `i = 0` sometimes being printed?

When you execute `map` with an *iterable* specifying 30 elements as are doing  here, by default these 30 tasks are divided into "chunks" based on the *chunksize* argument that you provide. Since we took the default *chunksize=None*, the `map` function computes a default `chunksize` value based on the length of the *iterable* and the pool size:

```py
chunksize, remainder = divmod(len(iterable), 4 * pool_size)
if remainder:
    chunksize += 1
```

In this the pool size was 4 and so the `chunksize` would have been computed to be 2. That means that each process in the multiprocessing pool are taking tasks of the task queue two at a time and so they are processing the *same object* twice with different values of `i` (which is ignored).

If we specify a *chunksize* of 1, so that each process only processes the object one at a time, then we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Acc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def multiprocess(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        result = pool.map(self.run, [1]*30, chunksize=1)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def run(self, i):
        print('i =', self.count, flush=True)
        self.count += i
        return self.count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Acc()
    a.multiprocess()
    print('a.count =', a.count)
```

Prints;

```
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
a.count = 0
```

And if we specify a *chunksize* of 30 so that a single process is processing all of the tasks against a single object:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Acc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def multiprocess(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        result = pool.map(self.run, [1]*30, chunksize=30)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def run(self, i):
        print('i =', self.count, flush=True)
        self.count += i
        return self.count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Acc()
    a.multiprocess()
    print('a.count =', a.count)
```

Prints:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
i = 10
i = 11
i = 12
i = 13
i = 14
i = 15
i = 16
i = 17
i = 18
i = 19
i = 20
i = 21
i = 22
i = 23
i = 24
i = 25
i = 26
i = 27
i = 28
i = 29
a.count = 0
```

**In this last case, of course, no multiprocessing occurred since a single process of the multiprocessing pool processed all the submitted tasks.**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I undestood.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the below approach if use of multiprocessing is mandatory.
As we want to run our code parallelly, I would not prefer to pass instance methods in `map`.
I would convert the `run` to a function instead of a method. which will take and argument and return the same.

```
def run(i):
    return i
```

then in the `multiprocess` method, I will loop for the return values of `pool.map` and add then to `self.count`

```
def multiprocess(self):
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    for r_value in pool.map(run, [1]*30):
        self.count += r_value
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

which gives output as

```
30

Process finished with exit code 0
```

complete code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run(i):
    return i

class Acc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def multiprocess(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        for r_value in pool.map(run, [1]*30):
            self.count += r_value
        pool.close()
        pool.join()



if __name__ =='__main__':
    a = Acc()
    a.multiprocess()
    print(a.count)
```

Comment: You have some serious indentation errors and you did not explain why the OP gets the output they get.